# Gradle Sync Failed within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to run a project in Android Studio 3.0, but the Gradle sync is failing every time. The Event log is showing the following errors:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (645ms)
```

Comment: Buddy can you please share your log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete the gradle folder from your home directory! i.e

> ~/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-name

where gradle-name is the distribution you have to delete. Then open android studio and open the project to sync the gradle afresh.

Answer (score -1):

Step1: Close android studio

Step2: Go to C:\Users\Khurshid.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all\2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo (if you want to configure gradle 1.12)

Step3: try to open the gradle-1.12-all.zip by double clicking it. If it gives error message then delete the zip file.

step4: go to https://services.gradle.org/distributions and download gradle-1.12-all.zip (54mb approx) and copy the same to the folder where you have previously deleted the zip file.

step5: open android studio and go to file->setting select 'gradle' and click on 'use local gradle distribution' and set 'gradle home' to 'C:\Users\Khurshid.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all\2apkk7d25miauqf1pdjp1bm0uo\gradle-1.12-all.zip' and click ok.

step6: It will download some file over the internet. If download doesn't start automatically then restart android studio.

step7: Be patience and let it download some important stuff and after that everything should be working fine. This method will help you save your internet data. Downloading the entire gradle directory will consume double the data.